# Отсеять фото без объектов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow, pil, pytesseract

Есть большое количество фото, хочу отсеять при помощи python фото без явных объектов на них- например фотографии неба, воды, стен итп, а оставить только фото на которых изображен человек, дом, мост итп. Каким модулем это сделать? На ум пришло только:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
import requests
import time

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image_link = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dk-find-out/image/upload/q_80,w_1920,f_auto/A-Alamy-BXWK5E_vvmkuf.jpg'
img = requests.get(image_link)
img_file = open('C:\\ocr\\images.png', 'wb')
img_file.write(img.content)
img_file.close()
time.sleep(5)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:\\ocr\\images.png')))
#далее отметаем фото без объектов
```

но силами pytesseract я нашел только чтение текста с фото, остальные методы вообще не туда.

Comment: Как вы объясните программе, где объект, а где картинка нарисованная, допустим, на стене? Без ИИ здесь не обойтись. Вот можно почитать https://wellsr.com/python/object-detection-from-images-with-yolo/

Comment: @СергейКох картинка тоже подойдет, мне нужно отсеять только ну очевидно пустые фото, типа фото воды, неба. я думаю если есть библиотека которая просто определяет название объекта на фото, то это подойдет, если ничего не определило- отсеиваем)